# 1 to 0..1 relationships with cascading deletes in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, edmx, entity-model

Assuming the following model, created in Entity Framework 4.3:
http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/files4/122585/bI2uq9a.png

We have:

- A Location Entity
- A company with a location
- A relationship: **location contains 0..1 companies.** This choice is necessary because the Location entity will be used by many more entities in our design.
- A cascading delete: when company is deleted, its corresponding location needs to be deleted too.

This is where it goes wrong: when generating a database from this model, Entity Framework pops up with the following error message:

http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/files4/122586/bgOPaZwqL.png

Translated the error message says:
`"End Company on relationship Model1.Store.CompanyLocation cannot have operation specified since its multiplicity is '*'. Operations cannot be specified on ends with multiplicity '*'."`

After investigating, we have noted that this indeed seems to not be possible, because Entity framework generates the following database(without the cascading delete):
http://www.dumpyourphoto.com/files4/122587/rx0g1G.png

The cascading delete indeed can't be made because Entity framework cheats a bit, it generates only 1 foreign key while keeping both navigation properties in its entities.

This is perfectly sensible and correct database wise, however it causes us trouble. We need this cascading delete, but also need the 0..1 relationship, because other objects in the database use the location entity in the same way as company. Does anyone have a solution for this, or advice on how to work around this?